# Using fractional em's in CSS's font-size property

Tags: css, font-size

Say, I have the following CSS rule defined:

```
.className {
font-size:0.89em;
}
```

My question is, how "deep" into fractions can I go while specifying 'em's for browsers actually to support it and for the font size to be rendered differently for a small fractional change in the em's value?

Comment: They seem to go pretty deep, I don't have any firm numbers that I could give, but checkout something like http://pxtoem.com/ and just play around. You'll see they can do whatever. I've seen ems set before like 0.631111111111111em and they worked. Whether or not that will be visibly different than 0.63em is unlikely though.

Comment: Very good. And it seems that most major browsers render even a slightest variation in the em's value with different looking font sizes. Why don't you post it as an answer and I'll check it as a correct one.

Comment: Ultimately, the smallest unit of scale is 1px, right?

Comment: @JohnB well I'm not talking about that extreme situation )) For me, I was curious, if, say, 0.89em would render differently than 0.88em and so on.

Comment: It seems like IE9 & 10 will round fractions to only two decimals. So 1/12em will be rounded to 0.08em, and 0.08em * 12px/em becomes 0.96px instead one 1px. This shouldn't be a problem as 0.96px should be rendered as 1px, right? Wrong again Bob. The IE-answer to this question is apparently "sometimes I do, sometimes I don't".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JohnB is right. We're still rendering in pixels whatever the size unit we use, and small changes in ems will not change the displayed size:

For example, for text originally displaying at a height of 20px*, we can see that there is no effective change when  a rule is added to make it .99em of its original height:

```
20 * 0.99 = 19.8
```

The browser can't display .8 of a pixel, so (assuming it will round up) it will still display it as 20px high.

Though it appears that browsers do not always round off as expected:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2010/02/10/rounding-off/

http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/

*Yep, I know a font-size of 20px doesn't alway mean it's displayed at 20px!

Answer (score 1):

It should be kept in mind though, that fractional em values, like all floating point numbers, are susceptible to rounding error.

I found that out while setting my media query boundaries, where one max-width was 0.00001em away from another min-width, and it was rounded up and both queries were activated. After changing the difference to 0.001em the queries worked as expected, exclusively.