# Is decimal precision when specifying a font-size respected by all browsers?

Tags: css, cross-browser, font-size

If I use the following CSS:

```
p {
    font-size: 20.5px;
}
```

Will all browsers draw that as `20.5px`, or will some round the value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using fractional em's in CSS's font-size property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656883/using-fractional-ems-in-csss-font-size-property)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are the decimal places in a CSS width respected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Decimals are not rounded consistently in all browsers. The best post I could find is here: [Browser Rounding](http://cruft.io/posts/percentage-calculations-in-ie/)

This contains a table that shows the following:

```
Internet Explorer 7 truncate to 2 decimal places
Internet Explorer 8 truncate to 2 decimal places
Internet Explorer 9 truncate to 2 decimal places
Internet Explorer 10    truncate to 2 decimal places
Internet Explorer 11    truncate to 2 decimal places
Firefox 3.0 truncate to 3 decimal places
Firefox 3.5 truncate to 3 decimal places
Firefox 31  truncate to 3 decimal places
Chrome 20   round to 15 decimal places
Chrome 21   round to 15 decimal places
Chrome 37   round to 13 decimal places
Safari 6 (OSX Lion) round to 15 decimal places
Safari 6.1 (OSX Mountain Lion)  round to 15 decimal places
Safari 7 (OSX Mavericks)    round to 15 decimal places
Mobile Safari 7 (iOS7)  round to 15 decimal places
Mobile Safari 8 (iOS8)  round to 15 decimal places
Chrome 36 (Jelly Bean) [Nexus5] round to 15 decimal places
Chrome 30 (KitKat) [S5] round to 15 decimal places
Android Browser 4 (Jelly Bean) [Nexus7,Nexus4,S4,S3]    round to 15 decimal places
Android Browser 4 (Ice Cream Sandwich) [Nexus,KindleFire2]  round to 15 decimal places
Android Browser 4 (Gingerbread) [S2]    truncate to 3 decimal places
Opera 12    truncate to 2 decimal places
Opera Next 24   round to 13 decimal places
```

Comment: The data you copied applies to rendering after defining it as percentages. Not when defining in `px` directly.

Comment: The page you reference does not refer to font sizes.

Answer (score 3):

All latest versions of browsers **allow for sub-pixel rendering***. See the [research](http://cruft.io/rounding/) and the table of [differences between browser versions](http://cruft.io/posts/percentage-calculations-in-ie/#browser-table).

Older browsers mostly round the pixels down. Most notable exception is IE8 and IE9 which round to the nearest integer (IE7 does also round down, IE10 and up use sub-pixel rendering).

<sub>* If you define the size in percentages, the value in pixels might be different as when you directly define it in pixels.</sub>

Comment: The page you reference does not refer to font sizes.

Comment: Sub-pixel rendering has nothing to do with font size. It's the ability to use the individual (usually red, green, and blue) sub-pixels and that up a pixel on your monitor to better render text.