# Font size in pixels and as fractional number

Tags: css, font-size

Can fractional number used to determine the amount of pixels font-size should have? I know that following syntax is allowed

```
.text { font-size:10.25684789em; }
```

But below described syntax is it allowed as well? Is it cross-browser syntax or some limitation is applied?

```
.text { font-size:10.25684789px; }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you can show me what `.25687489` of a pixel looks like I'd be impressed. Can be used...sure but the browser will round up/down as it desires.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656883/using-fractional-ems-in-csss-font-size-property?rq=1

Comment: @Paulie_D. thanks for you reply. It's abstract, I just wanted to emphasize that I need pixels in fractional numbers, though tenth for me will be more then enough :)

Comment: *"I need pixels in fractional numbers"*...Ok...but you won't actually get those fractions rendered is what I am saying....you can put `10.6px` if you like but the browser will render as 11px whether you like it or not.

Comment: I got your idea, thanks!

Comment: Text looks clipped from top when I give it font-size in fraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes the above syntax `.text { font-size:10.25684789px; }` will be support in browsers too....